# What is the best way to define a function that needs to be passed to another function?

Tags: python, class, keyword-argument, optional-arguments

Please consider the following code:

```
def build_matrix(x_coordinates, y_coordinates, calc_element, **kwargs):

    matrix = np.zeros((len(x_coordinates), len(y_coordinates)))
    for i in range(len(x_coordinates)):
        for j in range(len(y_coordinates)):
            matrix += calc_element(x_coordinates[i], y_coordinates[j], i, j, **kwargs)

    return matrix
```

The function `build_matrix` is used to build a matrix by filling up its elements using a function called `calc_element`. Since I don't know exactly what all the possible functions are that might be passed to this `build_matrix` function, I use optional keyword arguments so that I don't need to change `build_matrix` every time that I want to use it with another function (the only thing that all these functions have in common is that they need the arguments `x_coords_i, y_coords_j, i, j`)

However, I was wondering whether it would be Pythonic to use a class in this case instead of a function. For example, if I would define a particular version of `calc_element` in the following way

```
class calc_element_velocity_mass():
    def __init__(self, velocity, mass):
        self.velocity = velocity
        self.mass = mass

    def __call__(self, x_coords_i, y_coords_j, i, j):
        return self.velocity * i / x_coords_i - y_coords_j * j * self.mass
```

then after initialising it as follows

```
calc_element = calc_element_velocity_mass(20, 10)
```

I would be able to pass it to `build_matrix` without using optional keyword arguments, i.e., without passing for example `kwargs = dict(mass = 10, velocity = 20)` to `build_matrix`.

**Question:** Would this be a proper way of classes? And is my original implementation correct, or should I approach this in a different way? Thanks!

Comment: Either option seems reasonable to me. The main thing here is that `build_matrix()` defines how `calc_element` is used. If you are desinging `build_matrix` you have a lot of flexibility in what you decide that contract should be. Note that the current implementation allows `build_matrix()` to take empty `kwargs`, so the class  `calc_element_velocity_mass` will work with it as-is.

Comment: Well, for starters, `def __init__(self, **kwargs):` should probably just be `def __init__(self, velocity, mass)`. In any case, either works.

Comment: Note, the client fo your function coudl just pass `lambda x_cords_i, y_cords_j, i, j: calc_element(x_cords_i, y_cords_j, i, j, velocity=20, mass=10)` for example (i.e. using partial application). The important part is that your API is properly documented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class solution would definitely work, but a closure would be a much easier way to do the exact same thing:

```
def calc_element_velocity_mass(velocity, mass):
    def f(x_coords_i, y_coords_j, i, j):
        return velocity * i / x_coords_i - y_coords_j * j * mass
    return f
```

You could also return a lambda instead of `f`, but I used a named function here for clarity.

Comment: Yay for closures! That's such a great way to encapsulate a little state elegantly.